# How to get Romex between two garage doors

Tags: electrical, wiring, garage

I’m adding a bunch of new outlets to my 2-car garage as I turn one side into a workshop.
I’m trying to add one 240V outlet and two 120V outlets between the garage doors, but I can’t figure out how to get the Romex there and be able to drywall it after.
I originally thought I’d drill a hole up through the header, but I realized it’s two 2x10s against each other. Any ideas?

[image]
Outlets would go on the right side of this door. Romex for both 120 and 240 outlets is already up to the left side of the door.

[image]
Between the doors, where outlets would go.

[image]
Header between the doors.

[image]
Left side of door, close to where Romex is already at.

Comment: Why drywall and why Romex?  Use MC cable or conduit, leave the wall open for upgrades and maintenance.  Run the MC along the garage header, you don't need to go through anything.  Replace the installed NM and plastic boxes with all metal and use metal fronts.  The stud bays make great storage spaces, all your tools and a lot of your materials can go inside them, you get like 15% of your floor area back if your junk isn't hanging on drywall or sitting on the floor.

Comment: If you put outlets between the doors you should protect (box in) those safety eyes or you will eventually rip them off with a power cord.

Comment: @jay613 plus a box covering the GD sensors will make a convenient shelf!

Comment: Does anyone see an issue with putting a 240v outlet so close to an opening to the outside? GFCI Required? (2020 Edition of the NEC)

Answer (score 10):

Run THHN in EMT on the surface of the wall. It's a garage/workshop. It doesn't need to look like a living room, it can be *functional.*

Comment: Yes. Always a good idea not to drill into structural elements.

Answer (score 4):

Where the cables cross over the header and will not be in an enclosed cavity, have them in conduit.

In Fla. the inspectors look for the conduit to extend at least 1" past the inner edge of the drywall.

When finished it looks like the pic.  Not bad for a garage.

[image]

Comment: The UK has this sort of look everywhere. Usually in the kitchen living room or bathroom.

Answer (score 3):

They make drills bits that are longer than a foot. Try not to hit any nails.